# iphone - Is it necessary to create new app in itunes connect for in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm already having a free application in app store (itunes connect)
Now I want to add in-app purchase for that.
So, I created a new product in in-app purchase and trying to test it. Its saying the product id is invalid.
But I created new app in app store with product id's and when I'm testing, its working fine.
Is it necessary to create new app to distribute my old app with in-app purchases. Can't I add in-app purchase for already existing application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add in-app purchases to existing apps that previously did not support them.

Comment: I tried adding products to in-app purchases and its saying invalid product ID. How to debug it?

Comment: Check out this blog post on invalid product id scenarios: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Answer (score 0):

Is your device jailbroken? If so, you need to revert the jailbreak for IAP to work.